# tex to odt with pandoc eps images

Tags: image, latex, pandoc, eps

I tried to convert a tex-file into odt with pandoc. The troubles i got with the images. They are in eps-Vector-Format (created with R).

In tex, I can convert them with `epstopdf`, when using pandoc, the images are not imported.

```
pandoc --default-image-extension=eps -f latex -t odt -o x.odt y.tex
```

Error Message:

```
[pandoc warning] Could not determine
image size in `Fig_1.eps': could not
determine image type
```

Pandoc-Version (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
pandoc 1.19.2.4
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.5,
texmath 0.9.4.4, skylighting 0.3.3.1
```

I would rather not make two versions of the same tex-Document just for odt-Conversion. The remaining document converts just fine.

Comment: you could simply [convert the images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2873/33952)...

Comment: That's what I did now, thanks. Works more or less. Some issues I am having with: geometry package (obviously not recognized); captions (I use caption usepackage; and the command captionof; only labels are printed), graphicspath from graphics doesnt work either.

Comment: you should also try to update to the newest pandoc version...

Comment: Thanks, graphicspath at least works now :-).